# Change "add to home screen" image

Tags: youtube, home-screen-shortcuts, home-button

Is there an easy way to change the add to home screen image on Android devices?

I know how to change the HTML manually but for example I would like to change it for the YouTube web app for example.

Answer (score 1):

[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) let's you edit the image (by long-press on the shortcut icon) and change it with other app icons or icons provided by icon packs.

Example below shows the original shortcut icon of this question on left, followed by app icon (in middle) and using icon pack on the right.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted this but I am hopeful that there is a way to do this with a modified Javascript bookmarklet or something similar.  If nothing else I should be able to create custom HTML pages that redirect but is slopey.

Comment: Thanks, that's beyond me and likely the site scope too?

Comment: I think a self contained answer would be okay and on the site guidelines.